# Closed form of orthogonal projection onto a hyper-plane in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ constrained in the P.S.D. cone

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, closed-form, symmetric-matrices

Let $\mathcal{M} $ be a hyper-plane in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ constrained in the positive semidefinite (P.S.D.) cone, for example, $ \mathcal{M} $ could be:

$$ \mathcal{M} = \left\{ Q\succeq 0 \:\big\vert\: 1^TQ1 =0 \right\}, \text{where 1 is the vector of all 1's.} $$

For a symmetric P.S.D. matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, I'm wondering whether there exists a closed form solution (under any kind of inner product) of the orthogonal projection of $ A $ onto $ \mathcal{M} $, i.e., the closed form of

$$ {P}_{ \mathcal{M} } \left( A \right) = \arg \min_{Q \in \mathcal{M}} \|A - Q\|_2 $$

Comment: There are no positive definite matrices $Q$ for which $1^TQ1=0$, where $1$ is anything other than the zero vector. Maybe you mean some other $M$? Such as $\{Q:\operatorname{tr}( QA)=1\}$ or something?

Comment: I’m sorry it should be positive semi definite. I’ve edited the thread. Basically I want M to be in the form $x^T M x = c$.

Comment: What do you mean by "a hyper-plane in the space of P.S.D. matrices"?  The set of all psd matrices is not a vector space.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes. $A$ should be symmetric.

Comment: @user1551 I'm messing up the terminologies a little bit. I've already edited the thread.

Answer (score 1):

In the special case where $x=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$, your constraint equation $M=\{Q: x^TQx=c\}$ reduces to requiring only that the upper left  entry of $Q$ be equal to $c$.  Then it is easy to see that $P_M$ is given by the recipe: set all matrix entries equal to $0$, except for the $(1,1)$ entry which is unchanged, at least for the Frobenius norm.

The case of a general $x$ vector reduces to this by an orthogonal change of variable.

For example, if $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$ one can find an orthogonal matrix $U$ such that $U x =\|x\| e_1$.  Then the constraint $x^T Q  x=c$ turns into $e_1^T U^T Q U e_1 = \|x\|^2c$, that is, $e_1 \hat Q e_1 = c'$, where $\hat Q = U^T Q U$ and $c'=\|x\|^2c$. Then your $P_M$ is the composition of the simple projection described above and the maps $A\mapsto U A U^T$ and  $A\mapsto U^T A U$.   Maybe you should fill in the details of exactly which order these compositions should applied and how the matrix $U$ might be found.

Comment: Could you give an example to the change of variables?